# Async all the way vs. Task.Run on a simple calculation method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I've started to dive into aync programming and I want to execute a very simple add method as an async operation.

One of the things i've read is that truly async program does not require thread switching => that means `Task.Run(..)` can be avoided.

This is how I've implemented an add method:

```
public class TaskSimpleExample
    {
        public static void SimpleCalcExample()
        {
            // Will perform in background
            Task<int> resultTask = Task.Run(() => BeginCalcNumbers(6, 6));
            Console.WriteLine("Doing Work");
            Console.WriteLine("Doing More Work");
            Console.WriteLine("Doing Extra Work");
            resultTask.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Work is done!");
        }

        static int BeginCalcNumbers(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = Add(number1, number2);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            return result;
        }

        static int Add(int number1, int number2)
        {
            int result = number1 + number2;
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I understand that it has nothing to do with `async`. It just opens another thread and runs in the background.

I've failed to convert this code to use `async` & `await` (and eliminate `Task.Run`). Is it possible ? (Please notice I need to continue after the callback in other place in the method using `resultTask.Wait()`).

Comment: Why do you want to use async/await when adding two numbers? It seems rather superfluous.

Comment: You can't get rid of `Task.Run`, since none of your instructions used is asynchronous. So a `Task.Run` is the only thing you can await for in this example.

Comment: @JoakimSkoog adding to number is just an example to a CPU bound task

Comment: @msanz Can you further explain this line "since none of your instructions used is asynchronous" ?

Comment: @ohadinho it means that you're using synchronous code, so the only way to make your example asynchronous would be a Task.Run (i.e. in your Add method), make it `async` and then `await` every call upwards.

Comment: @msanz I've read that this is a bad practice to use Task.Run inside async implementation: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html

Comment: CPU-bound tasks are usually best kept on the thread that's already running, unless that thread is "special" and needs to be freed up (e.g. it's the UI thread)

Comment: It's unclear here what you are trying to achieve. async/await only makes sense if you know why you need them. Why use async/await in a program that is synchronous anyway?

Comment: @goaty Do you mean that I should use async \ await only in I\O operations ? In that case, why does a cpu-bound operation is an example to async and await here ? : https://www.dotnetperls.com/async

Comment: The *natural* place to add asynchrony to your code is where you find that there's a separate `XxxAsync` method already on offer to you. Frequently, though not exclusively, some I/O will be involved somewhere within that implementation. Once you switch from the `Xxx` method to `XxxAsync`, you'll find that `async`/`await` start naturally bubbling up through your code.

Comment: Can't you just make `public async static Task SimpleCalcExample(){}` and replace `resultTask.Wait();` with `await resultTask;`

Comment: @ohadinho No I didn't mean so :). You can use async/await to handle long-running cpu operations too, in which case you effectively schedule those CPU-bound operations to the background threads. So no reason to avoid that if that's the case

Comment: @goaty why shouldn't I just use Task.Run or Task.StartNew to handle long-running cpu operations ? I'm using it anyway. What is the added value to use Task.Run together with async and await? for instance:
await Task.Run(() => myService.CalculateMandelbrot());
why don't just:
Task.Run(() => myService.CalculateMandelbrot());
?
(Please check the answer below)

Comment: @ohadinho Task.Run() returns a Task which can be await-ed. Calling 'await' will actually wait for the function that you give Task.Run() to finish. Omitting 'await' will execute the immediate statement after   Task.Run().

Comment: @goaty so if I will omit 'await' in the example below - view would take control before I'm getting an answer, right ?
So the following is an equivalent to async and await ? : Task.Run(() => myService.CalculateMandelbrot());
Task.Wait();

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you know about `Task.Run` is absolutely correct and that's pretty much the point of using `Task.Run`

Using `Task.Run` will execute a method on a thread pool thread and return a task that represents the completion of the method.

As Stepthen Cleary suggest, you should use `Task.Run` only to call CPU-bound methods.

Another important thing to mention is that you should use `Task.Run` to actually call the method that does heavy CPU-bound work and not use `Task.Run` in the implementation of the method.

Here's a good example on how to use Task.Run properly:

```
class MyService
{
  public int CalculateMandelbrot()
  {
    // Tons of work to do in here!
    for (int i = 0; i != 10000000; ++i)
      ;
    return 42;
  }
}

...

private async void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => myService.CalculateMandelbrot());
}
```

Also you should read [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html) and [Task.Run Etiquette Examples: Don't Use Task.Run in the Implementation](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html) if you are interested in learning more about `Task.Run`

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. Can you expain why I can't just: Task.Run(() => myService.CalculateMandelbrot()); without the async & await keywords ?
Task.Run would run a background thread so why do I need async & await over here ?

Comment: That's pretty simple. First, you need the async keyword in order to use await keyword and without the await keyword your method will just run synchronously, which is something you don't want to do, because you will block the currecnt thread(let's say the UI thread) while waiting for your CalculateMandelbrot method to finish. 
Since Task.Run returns a task, by awaiting that task you make sure you wait for your CalculateMandelbrot to finish by not blocking the current thread.

Comment: "because you will block the current thread(let's say the UI thread) " 
But why am I blocking the UI thread if Task.Run runs this process in OTHER  background thread ?

Comment: Task.Run will the run the method you feed to it on a threadpool thread, but by awaing the task that Task.Run return you will make that you won't block the thread.